# Connected via UMTS but can't ping default gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, internet-connection, ping

I have a UMTS modem/Windows computer that can't connect properly to the internet.  It gets an active PDP context and Windows gets an IP address from DHCP, DNS and default gateway addresses.

But no browsing is possible, and I can't even ping the default gateway.

This is the output from ipconfig:

> Mobile Broadband Connection:
>
> Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
> Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx Mobile Broadband Network Adapter (Huawei)
> Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 58-2C-80-13-92-63
> DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
> Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
> Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse . : fe80::209f:7ec7:c55f:fcae%173(Bevorzugt)
> IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 10.43.60.185(Bevorzugt)
> Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
> Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.43.60.186
> DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.43.60.186
> DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : -1386730368
> DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-72-7E-5D-B0-99-28-CE-D6-E6
> DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 80.87.78.4
> 80.87.78.11
> NetBIOS ber TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

The same device and computer works fine with a SIM from a different mobile network, which would appear to rule out firewall problems.

Can anyone suggest a possible cause?
It was said to me that maybe "the IP network is incorrectly configured" - but what does that mean?  how could it be incorrectly configured?
The only false configuration that I can think of would be refusing static IP addresses, and that doesn't apply in this case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the troubleshooting option of Windows? Windows should be able to reset your DHCP server. If that doesn't work try going to command prompt and flushing the DNS.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  The problem is happening on many computers, and I often connect using different modems/SIM/APN/DNS addresses etc, with no problems.  So, no, I didn't think in terms of Windows IP stack problems up til now.  Do you think that's a false assumption?